# Get all properties of a class recursively C#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have a class which looks like

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; };
    public string LastName { get; set; }; 
    public Address Address { get; set; };  
}

public class Address 
{
    public string HouseNo { get; set; };
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }; 
    public SomeClass someclass { get; set; }; 
}

public class SomeClass 
{
    public string A{ get; set; };
    public string B{ get; set; }; 
}
```

I have figured out a way finding out Properties in a class which are primitive like the string, int bool etc using Reflection

But I also need to find out the list of all complex types in a class like for ex. class Address withing Class Employee and class SomeClass within Address

Answer (score 7):

If you already know how to use reflection, this should be easy:

```
private List<Type> alreadyVisitedTypes = new List<Type>(); // to avoid infinite recursion
public void PrintAllTypes(Type currentType, string prefix)
{
    if (alreadyVisitedTypes.Contains(currentType)) return;
    alreadyVisitedTypes.Add(currentType);
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in currentType.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} {pi.PropertyType.Name} {pi.Name}");
        if (!pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive) PrintAllTypes(pi.PropertyType, prefix + "  ");
    }
}
```

And a call like

```
PrintAllTypes(typeof(Employee), string.Empty);
```

would result in:

```
String FirstName
  Char Chars
  Int32 Length
String LastName
Address Address
  String HouseNo
  String StreetNo
  SomeClass someclass
     String A
     String B
```